# RegAsm : error RA0000 : Failed to load because it is not a valid .NET assembly

Tags: dll

espero me puedan ayudar ya que estoy batallando con registrar una DLL que esta hecha en C# (.NETFRAMEWORk 4.5) pero al ejecutar el archvo .BAT y registrar la DLL me sale el siguiente error: **RegAsm : error RA0000 : Failed to load 'C:\Users\Hecto\Desktop\Debug\PDFGenerador.dll' because it is not a valid .NET assembly**

pongo lo que contiene el archvo .bat

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
color 30 
echo ================================== 
echo = = 
echo = Inicio de Instalacion     = 
echo = = 
echo ================================== 
echo. 
echo. 
regasm /tlb /codebase PDFGenerador.dll
echo. 
echo. 
pause
gacutil /i PDFGenerador.dll
echo. 
echo. 
pause
regasm /tlb /codebase itextsharp.dll
echo. 
echo. 
pause
gacutil /i itextsharp.dll
echo. 
echo. 
pause
iisreset
echo. 
echo. 
echo =================================================================
echo = = 
echo = Proceso finalizado con exito presione una tecla para terminar = 
echo = = 
echo =================================================================
popd
pause
exit[/quote]
```

cualquier ayuda aportacion es bienvenida gracias

Comment: Sin tener el archivo que ibtebta regustar para revisar si es un ensamblado de .net valido no ws posible cobtestar la pregunta. Intebte verificar si el ensambkado es de .net https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/view-contents

Comment: Gracias por responder @MauricioOrtega , le cometo que realice el cambio de .net framework de 2.0 (que estaba originalmente) a 4.5 (que es el que necesito) , el cambio lo realice en el Visual studio por medio de Propiedades-aplicación- version del net framework de destino; ahi seleccione 4.5 . al intentar registrar despues la DLL se vino el error , que comento , cabe señalar que cuando estaba en 2.0 me dejaba registrar sin problema la DLL y no salia ningun error